# Polygon division with a square root

Tags: polynom, sqrt

I need to write a polygon division using `polynom` package, but my coefficients have square roots and the package gives me an error. Is it possible to make this division using `polynom`?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{polynom}

\begin{document}

\[
\polylongdiv[style=D]{x^6+(2\sqrt{2})x^5+2\sqrt{2}x^3+2\sqrt{2}x+7}{x-(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: From the documentation, p.3 "Polynomials  are  entered  as  you  would  type  them  in  mathmode:1you may use+,-,*,\cdot,/,\frac,(,), natural numbers, symbols like e,\pi,\chi,\lambda, and variables; the power operator^with integer exponents can  be  used  on  symbols,  variables,  and  parenthesized  expressions.   Never  use variables in a nominator, denominator or divisor.The support of symbols is very limited and **there is neither support of functions like sin(x) or exp(x), nor of roots or exponents other than integers**"

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes, thanks. In the hurry I missed that part of the documentation :(